# Overriding hashCode() and equals() in custom Spring security userdetails implementation

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in my custom Spring security `userDetails` in order to limit concurrent sessions in my application. According to my research, if you have a custom `UserDetailsService` implementation you have to override these methods in order for the concurrency strategy to work. I have tried this but it doesnt seem to work. What is the proper way to implement this??

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherUser) {

    ProcnetUserDetails other = (ProcnetUserDetails) otherUser;

   if (other.getUsername().hashCode() == hashCode()){
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return this.systemUser.getUsername().hashCode() ;


}
```

Comment: Please complete the question !!!    I have tried this but t: ???

Comment: Equality of hash codes does not generally imply equality of the objects themselves, which makes your `equals` look suspicious.

Comment: why are you calling hashcode from equals?

Answer (score 2):

Change your equals method to compare `userNames`, not their `hashCodes`

```
   return getUserName().equals(other.getUserName()));
```

Unequal objects can have the same `hashCode`, so your current implementation is definitely wrong.

Having said that, you haven't really *asked a question*.